# Как добавить в конретную форму поверхностный текст? HTML

Tags: html, wordpress, contact-form7

Поставлена задача: в поле "выберите услугу" пока конкретную услугу не выбрали нажатием мыши должен быть обычный полупрозрачный текст. Как мне это реализовать, подскажите пожалуйста.
`

```
<label> Ваше имя *
    [text* your-name] </label>

<label> Ваш e-mail *
    [email* your-email] </label>
<label> Выберите услугу *</label>
[select your-goods "Видеопродукция" "Графическая продукция" "Реклама в Интернете" "Размещение рекламы" "Фотопродукция" "Полиграфия"]

<label> Номер телефона *
    [tel* tel-client] </label>
<label> Комментарий</label>
[textarea your-message]
[submit "Отправить"]
```

`

Comment: Частично -C помощью CSS :) Но можно через jquery к примеру.

Comment: Допустим, как мне это реализовать?) Я даже не понимаю где лежит ответственный css файл для этой страницы... Это полное дно)

Comment: Что такое "обычный полупрозрачный текст. " в селекте?

Comment: Ну, знаете, в полях с выдвижным меню с перечнем услуг в поле, пока ничего не выбрано, серая не выделяемая надпись типа "Выберете услугу из списка". Эта надпись расположена непосредственно в форме. Тобишь в блоке, в который потом забивается выбранный параметр. Конкретно в моем примере кода - в качестве этой надписи служит первый элемент. А мне необходимо дополнить этот код так, что бы вместо первого элемента в select высвечивалась моя фраза. Надеюсь доступно объяснил :)

Comment: В CF7 это реализовать у меня не вышло. А начальник говорит, что через CSS этой формы делать не вариант(сам не знаю почему).

Answer (score 0):

Как то так (за основу можно взять):

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Selectable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <style>
    #feedback {
      font-size: 1.4em;
    }
    
    #selectable .ui-selecting {
      background: #FECA40;
      opacity: 0.7
    }
    
    #selectable .ui-selected {
      background: #F39814;
      color: white;
    }
    
    #selectable {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 60%;
    }
    
    #selectable li {
      margin: 3px;
      padding: 0.4em;
      font-size: 1.4em;
      height: 18px;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#selectable").selectable();
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <ol id="selectable">
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Видеопродукция</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Графическая продукция</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Реклама в Интернете</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Размещение рекламы</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Фотопродукция</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Полиграфия</li>
  </ol>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо Михаил. Этот шаблон подойдет для плагина CF7 в Wordpress?

Comment: Это просто заготовка html, не шаблон.